# oracle RAC expdp store dmp file in which node

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, expdp, oracle-rac

We have a linnux Oracle 11g RAC setup with two physical nodes and the instance names are ora_inst1, ora_inst2 and ora_inst

ora_inst1 running on node1
ora_inst2 running on node2
ora_inst running on both nodes

expdp system/password@ora_inst dumpfile="dumpfile" dumpdir="/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/log/"

When we run the above command Oracle store the dumpfile sometimes in node1 and sometimes in node2. How oracle chose the node in this case ?

Comment: It would depend on definition of ora_inst. By default, it would be round robin like. It can be configured to access ora_inst2 only in cases when ora_inst1 is not available. Or, if you target exact node, you may prefer to use ora_inst1 (or ora_inst2) in your command.

Answer (score 0):

Its depends on configuration of tns_alias (ora_inst). When you connect to the datbase using tns alias ora_inst, It will connect to node1 and node2 using SCAN name.